# Rollback and merge back in specific dev branch to Main branch

Tags: tfs

Im having two Dev branchs. Dev1 and Dev2. which has same set of code base with minimum changes. and one Main branch like a base branch.

1. Im moving Dev1 to Main
2. Rollback Dev1 changes from Main.
3. Moving Dev2 to Main
4. Again im moving Dev1 to Main. here i wil get the problem the rollback changeset will not move to Main.

So in which step i need to use /keepmergehistory to avoid this problem. And also do we have this option in VS UI?

Comment: Does the "move" here mean Merge? What error did you get in the step4?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in my environment(TFS2015.2 + VS2015.2) with the steps below, no issue occurred during the process, you may take a look at these steps:

1. Branch Dev1 and Dev2 from Main
2. Do some changes in Dev1 and Dev2, and check in them.
3. Merge from Dev1 to Main, check in the changes into Main
4. Rollback the changeset that just checked in to Main, check in the changes into Main
5. Merge from Dev2 to Main, check in the changes into Main
6. Merge from Dev1 to Main, check in the changes into Main